# How I can switch between Forms with VB?

Tags: vb.net, forms, events, controls, visibility

hi i have a vb application with two forms. With Form A I can start Form B and Form A is then visible=false. If I click on the red "X" on the right corner I want that form B close and Form A is visible true.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can setup something like this in FormB:

```
Private objFromForm As FormA

Sub New(FromForm As FormA)
    InitializeComponent()
    objFromForm = FromForm
End Sub

Private Sub FormB_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    objFromForm.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Basically, when FormA calls the constructor for FormB, it passes a reference to itself.  Then, in FormB's "FormClosing" event, you can use that reference to make FormA visible again before FormB closes.  Here's an example of this from FormA's side, with a button that makes a new instance of FormB visible and passes the reference to itself (FormA) to the FormB constructor:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim objNewForm As New FormB(Me)
    objNewForm.Show()
    Me.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically you can do like this ..

When calling FormB form FormA

```
Me.Visible = False
FormB.Showdialog
```

In FormB FormClosing event

```
FormA.Visible = True
```